# How to replay server response from .har file?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy, har, replay

I am new to this, this is my first question here.
Please guide me to improve.

Learning python automation.
Came across scenario to automate `"replay server response from .har file"`.

Could capture, HAR file

```
from browsermobproxy import Server

server = Server("~/browsermob-proxy")

server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

from selenium import webdriver
co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
co.add_argument('--proxy-server={host}:{port}'.format(host='localhost', port=proxy.port))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "~/chromedriver", chrome_options=co)

proxy.new_har
driver.get(url)
proxy.har
```

How can I replay server response from captured HAR file (offline) ?
Is it possible with python or any other ?
And what's the significance of replay server response ?

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this https://github.com/louisabraham/har2requests. It should convert the .har file into a python script.